# Localization of a 2-category

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, stacks, algebraic-stacks

I am looking for a basic reference about localization of 2-categories, possibly avoiding the full formalism of n-categories.

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/bicategory+of+fractions ?

Comment: The general discussion is in Section 1.2 of: Renaudin 06 (arXiv: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0603339 , doi: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jpaa.2009.02.014 , nLab: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/localization%20of%20a%202-category)